# resolvectl domain has two default domain routes on my interfaces

Tags: networking, dns

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

In the morning when I get into work, I open the lid on my laptop on (and it connects to the work wifi).

```
$ resolvectl domain
Global: 
Link 2 (enp0s31f6):
Link 3 (wlp2s0): ~. work.com
Link 4 (virbr0):
Link 5 (virbr0-nic):
Link 6 (lxdbr0):
Link 8 (vethbf98eb73):
Link 10 (docker0):
Link 95 (enx123456789abc):
$
```

I then connect my laptop into my work docking station (which has my ethernet connection).

I then check the dns domain routing via resolvectl and I get the following:

```
$ resolvectl domain
Global: 
Link 2 (enp0s31f6):
Link 3 (wlp2s0): ~. work.com
Link 4 (virbr0):
Link 5 (virbr0-nic):
Link 6 (lxdbr0):
Link 8 (vethbf98eb73):
Link 10 (docker0):
Link 95 (enx123456789abc): ~. work.com
$
```

My main concern is that I have both my work wifi interface (wlp2s0) and my work ethernet interface (enx123456789abc) with default domain routing (~.) and work domain routing (work.com). The way I understand **systemd-resolved** is that this means that any DNS request that I make will be resolved on both interfaces in parallel and its unclear which will result will ultimately resolve (I assume the first to return a result will be used).

Should both the wifi and ethernet connections have a "~." entry?

It seems to me that one of the should be taking precedence so only one interface should be listed as "~.".

---

Update 0:

Looks like I have **resolvconf** controlling **/etc/resolv.conf** and **systemd-resolved** acting as a Consumer of this file (rather than managing the file itself).

I am unsure if this is a desirable configuration. Should I be running **resolvconf** and **systemd-resolved** at the same time?

---

Update 1:

Found a launchpad bug report that indicated that upgrading from earlier versions of Ubuntu using **ifupdown**/**resolvconf** would leave **resolvconf** configured (which was the situation in my case) but doing a fresh install of Ubuntu no longer installs **resolvconf** by default.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1817903

I have uninstalled **resolvconf**, and pointed /etc/resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf and rebooted

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Apr 13 09:53 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
$
```

This has cleared up some of my previous issues. Amended original post to remove parts that are no longer relevant.

Comment: Is this symlink correct?  
maybe it should be pointing to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf  
  
`$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`   
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jul  4  2019 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`  
`$`

Comment: Ahhh [https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#/etc/resolv.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#/etc/resolv.conf) implies that symlinking to **/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf** means systemd-resolved is a provider and my configuration implies systemd-resolved is configured as a consumer ... so valid configuration

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181346/systemd-resolved-and-resolvconf-is-it-ok-to-have-both-installed this article asks the same question (should I have resolvconf and systemd-resolved installed at the same time?) but does not have a response :(